# ng-repeat filter used as ng-if

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm curious if it's an efficient/ optimal way to use the ng-repeat like a conditional.  So I want code to show if found selected is true, instead of creating a new var in the back-end.

```
<div ng-repeat="c in data.accounts|filter : { Selected : true }" > 
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if`together with the `ng-repeat` directive. The snippet assume that each instance of `c` has property `Selected`

```
<div ng-repeat="c in data.accounts" ng-if="c.Selected"> 
...
</div>
```

Only items with `Selected === true` will be rendered.

Comment: true I forgot to mention accounts is a 2d array, thus using filter.  So is it still optimal?